# MySQLi only showing one result

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a simple problem, that my MySQLi function only shows one row / result in var_dump:

```
$sql       = $db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$db_prefix.'_posts');
$row       = $sql->fetch_array();

var_dump($row);
```

That's it. The query in phpMyAdmin shows 3 results. This one only 1. It also doesn't work with fetch_assoc() or fetch_array().

Edit: Also, I want to have the keys of the table being listed as with "fetch_array()".

Comment: `fetch_all()` : http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a while loop:

```
while($row = $sql->fetch_row())
{
   var_dump($row);
}
```

Because `fetch_row()`, `fetch_array()`, `fetch_assoc()` will all return one row every singe time it's being called untill it is 'out of rows'.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to iterate your results.
You can always use something like this:

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.$db_prefix.'_posts'; 

    if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) { 
        while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){ 
            var_dump($obj);
        } 
    }
```

However this would output a lot of data (because of the var_dump).
For a clean output you could use

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM '.$db_prefix.'_posts'; 

    if ($result = $mysqli->query($sql)) { 
        while($obj = $result->fetch_object()){ 
            echo $obj->*sql_columnname_here*; // Repeat for all columns

        } 
    }
```

fetch_row() will only contain 1 row at a time

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$sql = $db->query('SELECT * FROM '.$db_prefix.'_posts');
$rows= $sql->fetch_row();

while ($row = $rows->fetch_row()) {
  echo $row[0]." ".$row[1];
}
```